# Access Expression help - Calculated fields

Tags: ms-access

I need some help with an Access expression. I keep getting a syntax error.
I'm trying to get a calculated field from the combination of another calculated field.
Note that the LaserCuttingRate field is also a Lookup field. So it's not a simple entry field. It becomes a selector of the 3 choices.

`IIf([LaserCuttingRate]="200",([CuttingTime]*200/60),IIf([LaserCuttingRate]="400",([CuttingTime]*400/60),IIf([LaserCuttingRate]="100",([CuttingTime]*100/60)))`

[image: Table Fields]

All help appreciated.
Cam

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a final close bracket.

There are 6 open brackets ( but only 5 closing brackets )

---

UPDATE - second issue

Two extra issues

- The checks on number either don't need, or shouldn't have double-quotation masks
- The final IIF also needs a false clause at the end (in the example below, 0).

Try this - I have put it into an Access database scratch table and it worked. (If relevant, note that I had LaserCuttingRate and CuttingTime set as doubles, as well as the Result Type for the calculated column).

```
IIf([LaserCuttingRate]=200,([CuttingTime]*200/60),IIf([LaserCuttingRate]=400,([CuttingTime]*400/60),IIf([LaserCuttingRate]=100,([CuttingTime]*100/60),0)))
```

Comment: Thanks @seanb - unfortunately I still get a syntax error

Comment: Added second set of fixes - quoted numbers and final false setting.

Comment: Thanks again @sean. I may have left an important part out of the intro, as it's not working yet. The Laser Cutting Field is a lookup field. I've made sure all the result types are the same, and also stripped any formatting (just in case it was playing with it.)

Comment: By 'lookup' I assume you mean that when you enter the data, it is (say) one of a few values from an external table. However, the data is still (say) 200, 400 or 600. Is this assumption correct? Secondly - it would help if you posted some example data (feel free to anonymise it - just have it as somewhat representative).